# Probability problem. Coin tosses.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

A coin is tossed until it gives either 10 heads or 10 tails. Player A bets on 10 heads and player B bets on 10 tails. The game is unexpectedly interrupted after 15 tossings with 8 heads and 7 tails observed. What would be the fair ratio to split the prize pool between player A and B?

I know the answer to that question and I know how to calculate the probability of 8 heads after 15 tosses. However I do not understand how to calculate the answer. Any help is highly appreciated

Update: as Lulu mentioned below those 15 toses are irrelevant. We have to try 4 toses more. If we enumerate them we will get 11 possibilities  to get 2 H and 5  possibilities to get 3 T. Thus we should divide the prize fund in 11/5 proportion.

Comment: You know the answer but you are unable to calculate the answer?  Could you explain?

Comment: What have you tried?  The probability of having exactly $8$ Heads after $15$ trials is not relevant; we are told that we are in that state.  The question now is:  what is the probability that $H$ wins given that $H$ needs $2$ and $T$ needs $3$.

Comment: Lulu, it is from online test. I just tried every choice to get the correct numeric answer. But I do not understand how to come to.

Comment: I thought this way and calculated that probability to get 2 H vs 3 T IS 1/2 I suppose. But it is incorrect answer.

Comment: In this case you can easily solve the problem by enumerating the cases.  After all, the question is just "what's the probability that you get $2$ Heads before you get $3$ Tails?"  Well, it can't take more than $4$ tosses to decide the matter so just consider the possible outcomes of $4$ tosses.

Comment: Also this problem is in conditional probability chapter this some how 8 of 15 tosses should influence and it is 6535/32678.

Comment: That is irrelevant, as I said.  We are in that state, we just care about the probabilities from that state.  Doesn't matter how likely it was that we reached that state.

Comment: Got it. You are right 11/5 since 11 variants to getting least 2 H and 5 to get 3T. Tgank you so much, Lulu

Comment: But why do we add 4 tosses? Not 5 or 3?

Comment: Because the game must be settled in $4$ tosses (might take fewer, but it can't take more).  $3$ might not suffice.  The sequence $TTH$ for example leaves both players needing one more.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I truly appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you should divide the prize according to the probability that a player would eventually have won.  If, say, the probability that $A$ would eventually have won was $p$, then you give $p$ times the prize money to $A$.

Thus:  The question here is:  "What is the probability that you get $2$ Heads before you get $3$ Tails?"

Note that this must be decided in $4$ tosses.  It follows that it is equivalent to the question "What is the probability that you get at least $2$ Heads in $4$ tosses?"  That is easily seen to be $\frac {11}{16}$, so that is the portion of the prize you should give to $A$.